# Newly created sqlite table isn't empty (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I've created a new sqlite table and I was surprised - my table isn't empty, it has one record (id == 1, Title == null). Why is it so?

```
[Table("PurchasesLists")]
public class PurchasesList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string title { get; set; }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a table creation code:

```
SQLiteConnection database;
string databasePath = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite().GetDatabasePath(filename);
database = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
database.CreateTable<PurchasesList>();
```

As a result, `(from i in database.Table<PurchasesList>() select i).ToList().Count() != 0`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm sure, that's new file, was not used before and i haven't used code to add new records.